# Fewest steps to partition a post-install added harddisk?

Tags: 11.10, partitioning

I have added 1 TB harddisk my system already has Ubuntu 11.10 on another drive, and I need a quick partitioning of the 1Tb HDD from linux: an 150 Gb  partition the rest just free.

How can I do that in a few steps?

EDIT: Gparted does the fastest job if you like GUI!For console: fdisk!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use software such as Gparted or in terminal:

`fdisk /dev/sda1(use your hdd instead)`

After editiing and writing changes update your fstab file.

To list hard disk's use:

`fdisk -l`

Comment: How can I see all drives available to know which sdxx is mine?

Comment: Gparted really works great!